# How do i implement a proper show hide /slideToggle functionality in this function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I have a function in jquery which displays images on link click and also has to hide the image when the link is clicked again.

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j('.links').click( function(){
        var linkclicked = this.id;
        var url = $j(this).attr('href'),
        image = new Image();

        image.src = url;
        image.onload = function () {
              $j('#image-holder'+linkclicked).empty().append(image);
            /* The above line shows the image on first click.
               Adding slideToggle hides the image again  */
            };
            image.onerror = function () {
                $j('#image-holder'+linkclicked).empty()
                                .html('That image is not available.');
            }
            $j('#image-holder'+linkclicked).empty().html('Loading...');
            return false;
        });
    }); 
function loadnow() {

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php $topicid=1; ?>
<a href="myimages/red-brick-wall-texture.jpg" class="links" id="<?php echo $topicid; ?>" >Show image</a>
<div id="<?php echo 'image-holder'.$topicid; ?>"></div>
<?php $topicid=2; ?>
<br><a href="/myimages/gymicon.JPG" class="links" id="<?php echo $topicid; ?>" >Show image</a>
<div id="<?php echo 'image-holder'.$topicid; ?>"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know where to write slideToggle as to enable show/hide function properly. There are two links here which show separate images. They are shown when clicked but the problem is to hide them on next click and make them
visible when clicked again and so on.

Comment: I've said it before, and I'm sure I'll be saying it again, but: please remember that JavaScript (and jQuery is 'just' JavaScript) works client-side; what we need to see is what the browser sees, not the script that generates what the browser sees. Please, post the (relevent, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML ('view source') from your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have your code here is not really quite right for `.slideToggle`.  You should not put the URL for the image in the `href` attribute of an `<a>` element because the link will try to go there on click.

The way `.slideToggle` works is well documented on the [docs page](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).  All you have to do is use the HTML `<img>` tag, which is made to hold images.  Then you `$().hide();` them when the page loads so they aren't shown.  All you have to do them is call the `.slideToggle()` function on the link click event.

See the working example with some misc pictures in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8xcZT/5/.

Or here is a working version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/JMXba/9/.  I can see this may be desirable to wait for the click to load the image.

Good Luck!

Comment: The above function is working properly.. also shows the loading status while images are loading..so i am more comfortable using the function, but the problem is $j('#image-holder'+linkclicked).empty().append(image); . This line is already showing the image once the link is clicked. Now if i use slideToggle , it does not work properly.. either hides/shows two times. So can you plz suggest how do i modify the baove function?

Comment: The problem is your code is not really made to work well with `slideToggle` but here is a working hack starting from your code: http://jsfiddle.net/JMXba/9/

Comment: Lovely Thanks a lot!!! But there is a small problem... In your code the line $j(this).attr('href','#'); ... When i click the link second time i.e to hide the image , the browser scrolls up.. I want it to stay over there only.. but its focus moves up. How can i fix this ? Plz help!

Comment: This is because the `.toggleScroll` method actually removes the images from the document (hides it) Pratik, remember to vote up my answer if you think it helped, even check it as correct if it is right;-)

Comment: You can fix this by making a div around the outside of all you HTML elements with a fixed height and width, this will be like the border for your site.  Things will move around inside, but not change the size of the border.

Comment: I actually replaced $j(this).attr('href','#'); with return false and it worked beautifully!! Many Thanks Jeffery for your time and patience!